# My check all checkboxes not working

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have this form that gets data from the database and displays checkboxes.I have a function to check and uncheck all boxes but its not working.can anyone please help?

```
      <form id="myform" method="POST" action="PHPMailer/examples/mail-exec.php">
   <div class="row">
  My Trailers :</br>
  <div class="form-group" style="overflow-y: auto; height:100px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Check_ctr" value="yes"     onClick="Check(document.myform.check_list)"><b>Check Control</b> </br>
   <?php 
   $qry="SELECT * from followers where vendorid =$vendorid";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( $qry );
  $stmt->execute();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="<?php echo      $row['email'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?><br>
 <?php } ?>     
 </div>                         
 </form>
```

here is the js function:

```
                <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                <!--

                <!-- Begin
                function Check(chk)
                {
                if(document.myform.Check_ctr.checked==true){
                for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                chk[i].checked = true ;
                }else{

                for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                chk[i].checked = false ;
                }
                }
                // End -->
                </script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/310/ check out this.

Comment: Please, when posting a JavaScript question, remember to post the relevant ([MCVE]) HTML; the PHP script that generates the HTML is usually entirely irrelevant to JavaScript (since the PHP is not sent to the client, only the HTML is).

Answer (score -1):

There is an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'check_list' of undefined` in your console

You need to assign the form's name to access it via document

```js
function Check(chk, list) {
  var checked = document.myform.Check_ctr.checked
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].checked = checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="PHPMailer/examples/mail-exec.php">
  <div class="">My Trailers :
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group" style="overflow-y: auto; height:100px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check_ctr" value="yes" onClick="Check(this, document.myform.check_list)" /> <b>Check Control</b> 
      <br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1">1
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="2">2
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="3">3
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="4">4
      <br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I had not given the form a name.

Comment: I am trying to use a foreach statement to pass values to the db and its giving me this error

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\admin\vendor\check.php on line 8

Comment: <?php

$data= $_POST['check_list'];

// optional
// echo "You chose the following color(s): <br>";

foreach ($data as $email){
echo $email;

}

?>